# Covariance matrix for 9 arrays using np.cov

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, covariance

I have 9 different numpy arrays that **denote the same quantity, in our case `xi`**. They are of length 19 each, i.e. **they have been binned**.

The difference between these 9 arrays is that, they have been calculated using jackknife resampling, i.e. by omitting some elements each time and repeating the same 9 times.

I would now like to calculate the covariance matrix, which should be of size 19x19. The square root of the diagonal elements of this covariance matrix should give me the error on this quantity (**`xi`**) for each bin (19 bins overall).

The equation for the covariance matrix is given by:
[image]

Here `xi` is the quantity. `i and j` are bins of length 19.

I did't want to write a manual code, so I tried with `numpy.cov`:

```
vstack = np.vstack((array1,array2,....,array9))

cov = np.cov(vstack)
```

**This is giving me a matrix of size 9x9 instead of 19x19.**

What is the mistake here? Each array, i.e. `array1, array2...etc` `all are of length 19.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the Example of the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) the shape of the output equals the number of rows squared. Therefore, when you have 9 rows you get a 9x9 matrix

If you expect a 19x19 matrix then you probably mixed your columns and rows up and you should use `transpose`

```
vst = np.vstack((array1,array2,....,array9))

cov_matrix = np.cov(vst.T)
```

Comment: Arrggggg...  I was so dumb to not notice this.. Thanks!!

Comment: One more query, does `numpy.cov` take into account the `N-1/N` ? I can see from the docs that it calculates just by using `N-1` !

Comment: @ThePredator : I think it divides by `N-1` which is the standard normalization as far as I know. Thus, it is possible that you have to multiply by the appropriate factor ...

Comment: you mean it divides the entire covariance matrix by `N-1` ? So if I want `N-1/N` I multiply by `(N-1)^2/N` ??